# Why do all empires gang up on the player in Birth of the Federation?

Tags: star-trek-birth-of-the-federation

Why do all empires gang up on the player in Birth of the Federation?  Is there any action I'm doing to garner their wrath?  Is there any way this can be avoided?

Comment: what fun would it be if the computer didn't gang up on the player?

Comment: @Xantec *Winning?*

Comment: I think he meant this kind of fun http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Losing

Answer (score 2):

You can bend over backwards and keep ONE of them friendly, sometimes. But no, they'll attack you pretty quickly on most difficulty levels.

What I usually try to do is hunker in a corner, building up. Sometimes they'll give you enough space to get competitive. One time I did that though,  and eventually emerged to find out that the Borg had taken over the entire Galaxy =P. They must have spawned right near me, and just expanded in the other direction.

Comment: I'm not sure if that joke is really appropriate

Comment: @ivo: Well, I was talking about giving them money and tech, but if bending over forwards works, run with it.